# Need to prove that two sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that (A\B)∪(B\C)=(A∪B)∖(B∩C).
I've already proven that (A\B)∪(B\C)⊆(A∪B)∖(B∩C), now I need to prove the reverse subset. 
I've defined x∈(A∪B)∖(B∩C), and converted to logical terms (x∈A∨x∈B)∧(x∉B∨x∉C), 
and thus ((x∈A∨x∈B)∧x∉B)∨((x∈A∨x∈B)∧x∉C)) (distributive property), which yields (x∈A∧x∉B)∨((x∈A∨x∈B)∧x∉C)). 
I don't know how to get rid of the x∈A on the right side in order to complete the proof.

Comment: Is there any assumption? Like $A^c \cap C$ is empty.

Comment: No assumption is given.